# Append xml to xml using python.I have two xml files which i need to merge .so is there anyway i can merge both files

Tags: python, xml, django

can anybody tell me how to append xml files using python

this is my file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<addressbook>
    <person>
        <name>Eric Idle</name>
        <phone type='fix'>999-999-999</phone>
        <phone type='mobile'>555-555-555</phone>
        <address>
            <street>12, spam road</street>
            <city>London</city>
            <zip>H4B 1X3</zip>
        </address>
    </person>
</addressbook>
```

and i want to append it to another xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
 </note>
```

Is there any module which can do this for me...

and the output i needed is :

```
<addressbook>
    <person>
        <name>Eric Idle</name>
        <phone type='fix'>999-999-999</phone>
        <phone type='mobile'>555-555-555</phone>
        <address>
            <street>12, spam road</street>
            <city>London</city>
            <zip>H4B 1X3</zip>
        </address>
    </person>
    <note>
        <to>Tove</to>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
     </note>
</addressbook>
```

And for now i need to read xml from files but later i need to get the xml response from server and the convert it into one xml file .So please if any one know that to it will help me alot......

Comment: Is there any nesting involved? If not, then you just concat the files...

Comment: Yep there is nesting involved

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: second file is not showing properly obove so i added it here...          <?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

Comment: You need to show what you want the output to be. And what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried lxml but i could not get the result i wanted ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: Removed old answer as the question changed considerably.

Using lxml:

```
addressbook_xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<addressbook>
    <person>
        <name>Eric Idle</name>
        <phone type='fix'>999-999-999</phone>
        <phone type='mobile'>555-555-555</phone>
        <address>
            <street>12, spam road</street>
            <city>London</city>
            <zip>H4B 1X3</zip>
        </address>
    </person>
</addressbook>"""

note_xml = """<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
 </note>
"""

from lxml import etree

# XML strings to etree
addressbook_root = etree.fromstring(addressbook_xml)
note_root = etree.fromstring(note_xml)

# append the note
addressbook_root.append(note_root)

# print the new addressbook XML document
print etree.tostring(addressbook_root)
```